# color primary de configuración en tailwind no está funcionando

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, tailwind, vite

Estoy trabajando con reactjs, tailwind, postcss, y vitejs, y tengo mi configuración de tailwind:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: '#16425b',
        secundary: '#81c3d7',
        wall: '#d9dcd6',
        accent: '#2f6690',
        extra: '#3a7ca5'
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

y quiero que un ícono tome un color de acuerdo a un valor de un useState. El ícono toma el color primario de mi configuración de tailwind si el valor del useState corresponde con el asignado de ese contenedor, o por lo menos se supone que esa es la idea. Lo que pasa es que cuando levanto la aplicación, el ícono no toma el color, pero la barra de navegación, que tiene asignado el background primario, sí lo toma, y ya me he asegurado que el color primario esté bien configurado. Cuando la aplicación está corriendo y cambio el color del ícono de primario a otro color de la configuración de tailwind, como podría ser accent, sí toma el color, pero cuando lo vuelvo a cambiar al color primario, este no lo toma. Y si tumbo la aplicación, y cambio de color primario a accent (que estaba funcionando) y hago el npm run dev, entonces el ícono no toma el accent, pero si cambio de accent a primary con la aplicación corriendo, entonces ahí sí toma el color primary, y si lo vuelvo a cambiar a accent, no lo toma. Y no se cuál es el problema.

index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

postcss.config.js:

```
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

main.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from './store';
import { App } from './App.tsx'
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

navbar.component.tsx (es en este componente que ocurre el error):

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { INavbarProps } from "./interfaces"
import { RiHome4Fill, RiSettingsFill } from "react-icons/ri";
import { INavigationOption } from "../../utilities/navigation/interfaces";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const NavbarComponent = ({options, className}: INavbarProps):JSX.Element => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<string>('home');

  const OPTION_CONTAINER_STYLE = `px-3 rounded h-10 flex items-center cursor-pointer`;

  const handleRedirection = (e: React.MouseEvent, url: string, name: string) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSelectedOption(name);
    navigate(url);
  }

  return (
    <nav className={`md:hidden fixed bottom-0 h-16 left-0 right-0 w-full bg-primary flex justify-center items-center gap-5 rounded-tl-2xl rounded-tr-2xl ${className}`}>
    <ul className='flex justify-center items-center w-full h-full gap-8'>
        <li className={OPTION_CONTAINER_STYLE}
          onClick={(e) => handleRedirection(e, '/', 'home')}
          key={0}
        >
          <div className={`${selectedOption === 'home' ? 'bg-wall rounded-full p-3' : ''} ${OPTION_CONTAINER_STYLE}`}>
            <RiHome4Fill className={`cursor-pointer text-wall ${selectedOption === 'home' ? 'text-primary' : ''}`}/>
          </div>
        </li>
        {
          options.map((option: INavigationOption, index: number) => (
            <li className={`cursor-pointer ${selectedOption === option.text ? 'bg-wall rounded-full p-3' : ''} ${OPTION_CONTAINER_STYLE}`}
              onClick={(e) => handleRedirection(e, option.redirectUrl, option.text)}
              key={index + 1}
            >
              <div className={``}>
                {React.cloneElement(option.icon, {className: `text-wall ${selectedOption === option.text ? 'text-primary' : ''}`})}
              </div>
            </li>
          ))
        }
        <li
          className={`cursor-pointer ${selectedOption === 'settings' ? 'bg-wall rounded-full p-3' : ''} ${OPTION_CONTAINER_STYLE}`}
          onClick={(e) => handleRedirection(e, '/settings', 'settings')}
        >
          <div className=''>
            <RiSettingsFill className={`text-wall ${selectedOption === 'settings' ? 'text-primary' : ''}`}/>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}
```

Aquí muestro las líneas de código donde establezco el color del ícono como primario:

```
<li className={OPTION_CONTAINER_STYLE}
          onClick={(e) => handleRedirection(e, '/', 'home')}
          key={0}
        >
          <div className={`${selectedOption === 'home' ? 'bg-wall rounded-full p-3' : ''} ${OPTION_CONTAINER_STYLE}`}>
            <RiHome4Fill className={`cursor-pointer text-wall ${selectedOption === 'home' ? 'text-primary' : ''}`}/>
          </div>
        </li>
        {
          options.map((option: INavigationOption, index: number) => (
            <li className={`cursor-pointer ${selectedOption === option.text ? 'bg-wall rounded-full p-3' : ''} ${OPTION_CONTAINER_STYLE}`}
              onClick={(e) => handleRedirection(e, option.redirectUrl, option.text)}
              key={index + 1}
            >
              <div className={``}>
                {React.cloneElement(option.icon, {className: `text-wall ${selectedOption === option.text ? 'text-primary' : ''}`})}
              </div>
            </li>
          ))
        }
```

El componente  que tiene la clase bg-primary, sí establece el background con el color primary.

Comment: Cuál es el path de `NavbarComponent`? Quizá puedas agregar `"./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",` a tu tailwind.config.js